# How can i block a picturebox from moving further when it collides with another object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have made something like a game in C# where the character is a picture box and it is being moved using the arrow keys. I want him to stop when he meets a solid object (I use invisible square panels to define the banned areas) but the code I use makes him move in opposite directions when he is in touch with the panel and I press a different key.

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            j_figure = 2;
            x += velocity;

            if ((playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds) || playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)))
            x -= velocity - 10;
            playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            j_figure = 1;
            x -= velocity;

            if ((playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds) || playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)))
                x += velocity + 10;
            playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            j_figure = 3;
            y -= velocity;

            if ((playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds) || playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)))
                y += velocity + 10;
            playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            j_figure = 0;
            y += velocity;

            if ((playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds) || playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)))
                y -= velocity - 10;
            playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
```

Comment: sounds like you need to understand the code that you have written and learn to use the debugger.. it the results effects are not what you expect perhaps you need to change something in the direction that your objects are moving sounds like an `XY` issue to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. The problem was solved by adding
    `playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);`
inside every movement key action. More specifically:

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            j_figure = 2;

            x += velocity;
            playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);

            if (playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds))
            {
                x = panel1.Left - playerBox.Width;
            }
            else if (playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds))
            {
                x = panel2.Left - playerBox.Width;
            }
         }
...

// code for other directions
...
// again but this time outside the KeyCode if statements
playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make stop the object exactly at banned areas, you must set its location according to the areas bounds and its own size. For the left and right keys this would be:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) {
    j_figure = 2;
    x += velocity;
    if (playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds)) {
        x = panel1.Left - playerBox.Width - 1;
    } else if (playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)) {
        x = panel2.Left - playerBox.Width - 1;
    }
} else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) {
    j_figure = 1;
    x -= velocity;
    if (playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel1.Bounds)) {
        x = panel1.Right + 1;
    } else if (playerBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)) {
        x = panel2.Right + 1;
    }
} ...
playerBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

This logic has to be applied to the vertical directions accordingly.

Make the invisible areas visible for testing.

Comment: It works but not completely. When it happens for the character for example: to stop exactly on the object when he moves left and then I press let's say the key to move up, he reappears in the bottom of the object. The opposite happens when he stops exactly on the right side of the panel and I press the down key, he reappears on top of the panel.

Comment: There might be a overlap of one pixel, so add one pixel when on the right side and subtract one when on the left side.